# Small "Pyramid Escape" text-based game

Tags: c++, beginner, adventure-game

I'm extremely amateur when it comes to C++ in general, but I wanted to make a little "Pyramid Escape" text based game. I'm not done whatsoever but before I continue I want to see what I could possible do differently.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  TextFiles
//
//  Created by Neal Carico on 3/12/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Nedev. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

string start;
string restart;
string dead;
int turn1;
int turn2;
int turn3;
int turn4;
string decision1;
string decision2;
string decision3;
string decision4;
string decision5;
int random1;
int random2;
int random3;


while(restart != "dontrestart" || dead != "false"){
cout << "Welcome to the worlds largest pyramid. . . Type 'start' to enter or 'leave' to walk away..." << endl;
cin >> start;

///The Start
if (start == "start"){

///The main part of the game.

    cout << "Oh no! The pyramid collapsed trapping you in. You are the only one alive. . ." << endl;

    int score=0;

    cout << "Okay. So you have two options here. . .Left(1) or right(2)?" << endl;
    cin >> turn1;
    if(turn1 == 2){
        cout << "BAM! The roof collapsed over you and you die. Sad stuff" << endl;
        cout << "Thank you for playing. Your score was " << score << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "You took the left path. And then BAM! The path to the right collapsed... lucky you." << endl;
    score++;
    cout << "There gold on the ground.. do you pick it up?[y/n]" << endl;
    cin >> decision1;

    if(decision1 == "y"){
        cout << "You greedy bastard you. Lucky I like the irony and am not going to kill you in this instance... You find 10 gold." << endl;
        score = score + 10;
    }

    cout << "You start heading forward again and come to another turn. But this time there are actually four options... :)" << endl;
    random1 = rand() % 4 +1;
    cout << "Your options are as follows. 1) Up to right 2)Down to right 3)Up to left and 4)Down to left. This one changes everytime ;). The random number is " << random1 << endl;
    cin >> turn2;
    if (turn2 == random1) {
        cout << "BAM! The roof collapsed over you and you die. Sad stuff" << endl;
        cout << "Thank you for playing. Your score was " << score << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Sweet. You made it. There's a point." << endl;
    score++;

    cout << "Okay you start walking down the tunnel and something is moving in the distance. Do you approach it or head back to one of the other tunnels?(continue/return" << endl;
    cin >> decision2;
    if(decision2 == "continue"){
        cout << "Yup, I'm not nice enough to give you a break 2 times in a row. Dead." << endl;
        cout << "BLAAAHHHGGGG!! The figure is a crazed mummy who attacks you and you die. Sad stuff" << endl;
        cout << "Thank you for playing. Your score was " << score << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "There is a screeching sound as you turn around." << endl;
    score++;




///End of game stuff

}else if(start == "leave"){
    cout << "You walked away and heard a huge BOOM and saw the pyramid collapsed trapping the tour group in. You are" <<
    " one lucky person. Sure you lived, but you didn't even play the game. How lame.You can type 'restart' to try again, but you're always going to be a loser to me." << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Error. Please type restart or 'dontrestart' (notice there are no spaces) to exit the game..." << endl;
}
    cin >> restart;
    if (restart !="restart"){
        exit(1);
    }

}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Objects would be good.  See [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49614/text-based-adventure-game-with-too-many-conditional-statements/49636#49636) to a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `using namespace std;`, or any other namespace, for that matter. This can cause you have load functions with the same name, which can cause problems. This is discussed in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Second, you have a ton of variables you never use, including:

```
int turn3;
int turn4;
string decision3;
string decision4;
string decision5;
int random2;
int random3;
```

Third, you should use move functions.  One candidate for a function is asking whether to restart the game.

Fourth, I would use `bool`s for `dead` and `restart`.  You will need to convert the input for `restart`, but it better represents what is happening.

Fifth, you should consistently indent your code at 4 spaces per level.  You do this for the most part, but you do not do this in `main()`.

Comment: I saw on some other code that I shouldn't use namespaces, but they seem so helpful! As for the unused variables, I plan to use them eventually. Which is why I said it's not done. Thanks for your comments. I'll look into adding functions.

Comment: But, one question. Would it really be more efficient to add "std::" to all my `cout` and `cin` commands?

Comment: @NealC I don't know about efficient, but much safer.  If you start having ambiguous calls, you will have to do this anyway so the system knows which one to call.

Comment: There is not a problem with `using namespace std` in a program you write as long as you do NOT use it in a header file and as long as no other namespace you use contains conflicting names.  If you just want to import specific items use can do so as with `using std::cout`.

Comment: @NealC Listen to Edward.  He is better at this than I.

Comment: @Edward I'm guessing that would work for other commands like `using std::cin` ?

Comment: Yes, that would work.